# Why did the space shuttle tank look like a big orange banana

Tags: space-shuttle, liquid-fuel, fuel-tank

Why did the space shuttle's external fuel tank look like a big orange banana?  Why that design, and how come no one makes fun of it (Other than me right now heh heh)? While we're on the subject, what's the history behind this design, was it planned to be that way, or were there other proposals?

Comment: I know there were other proposals like the Saturn-Shuttle https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn-Shuttle

Comment: The two most obvious visual traits of a banana are that it is *curved* and that it is *yellow*. I really don't see how the STS ET looks like a banana at all.

Comment: @JörgWMittag have you never seen a shuttle tank before?!?! the darn thing looks like a straightened out banana!

Comment: The two most obvious visual traits of a banana are that it is *curved* and that it is *yellow*. The Space Transportation System External Tank is not curved (it is straight) and it is not yellow (the ETs of STS-1 and STS-2 were white, all others orange-ish). In other words, the STS ET has none of the traits that make a banana look like a banana, i.e. it only looks like a banana if you ignore everything that makes a banana look like a banana. By that same argument, it also looks like a horse.

Comment: Here's a photo of STS-1 on the pad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-1#/media/File:Columbia_STS-1_arrival_at_launch_pad.jpg

Comment: @JörgWMittag have you ever heard of a freaking comedic comparison? I was trying to be funny and bring it down to understandable terms.

Comment: is this not just a dupe of https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/why-do-the-shuttles-external-tanks-appear-to-be-rusted?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12671/what-exactly-is-the-orange-insulation-foam-used-on-many-different-launch-vehicle?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ErinAnne I am assuming that this question was more about the shape than the color?

Comment: @ErinAnne  Admittedly those questions don't cover "...how come no one makes fun of it (Other than me right now heh heh)?" or the important fruit-similarity aspects of this inquiry.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, STS-1 and STS-2 could have looked like peeled bananas ;)

Comment: @GdD THANK YOU! finnally someone agrees!

Comment: I so don't @DekoRevinio.

Comment: Um... This is not suitable for the site

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a joke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tank's color is that of its [insulating foam](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12671/what-exactly-is-the-orange-insulation-foam-used-on-many-different-launch-vehicle).
(STS-1's and STS-2's tanks were painted white to protect the foam.  But the protection turned out not to be needed, so thereafter the paint was omitted to save a few hundred kg.)

Its shape is (as usual) a tradeoff between aerodynamic drag, mass, strength, heat transfer, and cost.

I'm unaware of alternative designs that were rejected.

Comment: You might want to add that STS-1's and STS-2's ETs were painted white in order to protect the foam from UV radiation. However, it was found that the foam didn't really need protecting and that the paint added hundreds of kilograms of useless excess weight, so it was left off starting with STS-3.

Comment: Or just look at this old q&a https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2449/6944

Comment: more here: [Why is the shuttle's external tank's metal skin painted the same dark color as the foam insulation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15377/12102)